# nested multicols with itemised list

Tags: lists, multicol, nesting

Is there any way to reduce the column separation in `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` in the following MWE to be the same as `\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}`. Also how can I remove the column separation rule in the list?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.6pt}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item  Item 1
\item  Item 2
\item  Item 3
\item  Item 4
\item  Item 5
\item  Item 6
\item  Item 7
\item  Item 8
\item  Item 9
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the separation rule disappear by setting the length in the optional argument to the inner `multicol` environment; the separation in the inner environment remains 1cm, as shown by the example below, where the bullets are flush to the margin and the separation is just the same as the main one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.6pt}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{2}[\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}]
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item  Item 1
with some more text
\item  Item 2
with some more text
\item  Item 3
with some more text
\item  Item 4
with some more text
\item  Item 5
with some more text
\item  Item 6
with some more text
\item  Item 7
with some more text
\item  Item 8
with some more text
\item  Item 9
with some more text
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]